# Is there a French IPA translator for free?

Tags: ipa, french, online-resources

I am looking for a completely free French IPA translator as I'm currently attempting to learn the language and need help understanding the pronunciation. Looking for a text translator, audio optional

Comment: What have you found so far, and, if any, why don't these sites match your needs?

Comment: translate.google.com provides sound files for words and even clauses. It might help you.

Comment: May search French phonology in Wiktionary and wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

Here's a free tool that provides multi-word transcriptions https://french-to-ipa.vercel.app/

Answer (score 1):

The [Collins online dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/incroyablement) provides IPA transcription as well as sound files, and it is free / unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://easypronunciation.com/en/french-phonetic-transcription-converter
The site offers a number of additional functionalities.
It probably addresses your needs.

Comment: This is free in the sense that if you don't mind waiting an hour between queries, you can get something.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Open IPA.
It is a free text to IPA transcription service.
However, it does NOT feature audio.
Here is the link:  https://www.openipa.org/transcription/french

Answer (score -1):

You can try
https://translate.yandex.com/
on-line translation service (French / English sentences), which gives IPA for the word you selected; does not support IPA for sentence and/or liasons, though.  Gives translation examples.