# Is there any free API that can translate from French to IPA?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, resource-request, phonemes, french

I have invented a language that actually is just French but each phoneme is replaced by another one. So to build an application that can translate from French to that language, I need the phonetics of French words. I checked out a lot of dictionary APIs (not to confuse with IPA), but have failed to find any free ones that work and that can give me a phonetic transcription. There are not really any rules in French on how to pronounce stuff, there are so many exceptions.

There might be a way to translate from French to a language like Turkish where every word is pronounced as it is written, it might be easier to find an API for translation rather than transcription, but still, didn't really find any API that I could make work (I'm not that good at Javascript), and translating to turkish first would be kind of a nightmare.

I tried PONS dictionary API, with only a NOT FOUND in the console, LibreTranslate that I did not understand at all, Collins did not answer to my mail...

I will also ask on Stack Overflow as this is sort of a programming question, but I thought maybe there could be a way to sove this with linguistics rather than with coding.

Comment: I do not agree that [Is there a French IPA translator for free?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/35987/is-there-a-french-ipa-translator-for-free) is the same question, I am asking for a more specific thing and did not find any working answers on that question.

Comment: There are quite strict rules about how to pronounce things in French. Exceptions are fairly rare, particularly compared to a language like English. Sure, you’ve got things like <ai> being /e/ in 1s future but /ε/ in 1s imperfect, or <s> being silent in _plus_ but pronounced /s/ in _plus_ – but the majority of the language is regular. The rules are just more complex than in Turkish or Finnish.